# Logrotate wtmp `su prime gadmin` Contabo Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, logrotate

Logrotate gives error in Ubuntu server 20.04 from Contabo VDM:

```
Oct 31 00:00:01 foo logrotate[364456]: error: wtmp:3 unknown user 'prime'
Oct 31 00:00:01 foo logrotate[364456]: error: found error in /var/log/wtmp , skipping
```

I have in `/etc/logrotate.d/wtmp`

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    su prime gadmin
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}
```

Ownership:

```
-rw-rw-r--  1 root    utmp             160128 Oct 30 23:10 wtmp
```

There is no user `prime` in `passwd` and there is no a `gadmin` command.

Any ideas what is that record and how to make it workable?

I simply commented out the first line for a test. It looks like Contabo provides customized distributions for their servers.

Comment: Why do you try to use a username that does not exist?

Comment: This is a new Ubuntu 20.04 server from Contabo. I just found the error in the system log.

Comment: I guess you will have to ask Contabo why they put it there. That is not standard ubuntu. You can remove it with no ill effect.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the questionable instruction fixed the problem.

```
/var/log/wtmp {
    missingok
    monthly
    create 0664 root utmp
    minsize 1M
    rotate 1
}
```